# Load in incremental mode a smartfield with a lookupcall

Tags: java, eclipse-scout

I defined a lookupcall to make a sql select on a table on my DataBase, unfortunately for some key return more then 1000 rows and for other less then 200 rows (the range is between 80 to 6600).
The smartfield show only a small part of them.

I want use a incremental load mode but I can't locate when the user arrives at the last element in the smartfield list to load the next range of rows.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to load a set of datas when the limit has been reached.

I can only suggest you to use a tree view via the `getConfiguredBrowseHierarchy` on the `AbstractSmartField`. This way you can show some master categories, then the user cliks the category and you load the child data via `getDataByRec` on the `ILookupCall`.